# How to use different jwt secret to verify the request?

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, nestjs, token

In my Nestjs project, I am trying to use different jwt secrete to verify the request. It could try the second secrete if the first one is failed.

Here is my code:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    private readonly userService: UserService
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([
        (request: Request) => {
          return request?.cookies?.Authentication;
        },
      ]),
      secretOrKey: configService.get('JWT_SECRET'),
    });
  }
}
```

I have tried to use try/catch, but it can not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need different secrets to verify the requests, that won't give you any extra security.

Comment: Hi, in my case,  I have to use muti secrets.

Comment: can you explain the use case?